# How to convert string to a list of json in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a string in the form of
`[[sourceId:111, clientId:12345, clientName:testclient, module:test,source:Request, userName:Michelle Jackson],[sourceId:112, clientId:1233, clientName:testclient2, module:test,  source:Request, userName:Michelle Jackson]]`

How do I convert it into a valid python list of json  ?

Comment: The problem is from where the string is generated. That is not a proper JSON format. If you have control over the source then fix it at source.

Comment: The problem is I do not have control over source

Comment: First,you shoud convert your data to dict  style,just like:
`[[{'sourceId':111},{'clientId':12345},{'clientName':'testclient'},{'module':'test'},{'source':'Request'},{'userName':'Michelle Jackson'}],
 [{'sourceId':112},{'clientId':1233},{'clientName':'testclient2'}, {'module':'test',{'source':'Request'},{'userName':'Michelle Jackson'}]]`
Your current data format has a syntax error in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Although I never recommend doing this, here's the code

```
import re
arr = []
for x in s.split('],['):
    kv = re.sub('\[|\]', '', x)
    arr.append(dict(kvi.split(':') for kvi in kv.split(',')))
```

NOTE: If the string is system generated, it's better to get it in JSON format in the first place.